# Tell the Rust compiler that a returned value doesn't hold the reference provided in the constructing function

Tags: rust, reference, return-value, borrow-checker

I have some structs containing some data that look like this:

```rust
struct A {
    // Some data
}

struct B<'s> {
    a: &'s mut A
    c: C<'s>
}

impl<'s> B<'s> {
    fn new(a: &'s mut A, d: &'s D) -> B<'s> {
        let c = C::new(d);
        B { a, c }
    }

    fn extract_c(self) -> C<'s> {
        self.c
    }
}

// A smart pointer provided by a library
struct C<'s> {
    d: &'s D,
    // Other fields holding some data, not referencing A
}

struct D {
    // Some other data not referencing A in any way (provided by a library)
}
```

I also have functions that that create and modify said structs like this:

```rust
fn modify(b: &mut B) {
    // Modifies b.a and b.c
}

fn construct_c<'s>(a: &'s mut A, d: &'s D) -> C<'s> {
    let mut b = B::new(a, d); // C is created in B::new
    modify(&mut b);
    b.extract_c()
}
```

I want to use `construct_c` somewhere else such that I can make another reference to A after obtaining the result from the call, like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut a = A::new();
    let d = D::new();
    let c = construct_c(&mut a, &d);  // First mutable borrow of `a`
    println!("{a}");   // Second borrow of `a`
    let result = do_sth_with_c(c);  // Move of `c`
    do_sth_with_a(a);
    // Some other code...
}
```

However, when I try to do that, the compiler says that when I call `do_sth_with_c`, I am using the first mutable borrow of `a`, even though `c` doesn't hold the reference to `a` provided to `construct_c`.

When I removed `println!("{a}");` and `do_sth_with_a` the code compiles, but I really need to print that information and do it before calling `do_sth_with_c`. Is there a way to tell the compiler that `C` knows nothing about the reference to `a` and that it is safe to make new references after calling `construct_c`?

**EDIT 1:**
When I substituted all the references `&mut A` with `Rc<RefCell<A>>` the code compiles. But is there another way without using `Rc` and `RefCell`?

**EDIT 2:**
Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77664341/23104921), introducing another lifetime to `B` seems to resolve the issue.

*How `B` changed:*

```rust
struct B<'a, 's> {
    a: &'a mut A,
    c: C<'s>,
}

// All functions that use `B` need to be updated as well
```

Comment: Can't write a proper answer right now, but in short - you've told the compiler that the borrows are connected, by using the same lifetime for both fields of `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote in a comment about `C`, "some other data not referencing `A` in any way". But by using the same lifetime you're telling the compiler that they *are* related. So, change your definitions from

```rust
struct B<'s> {
    a: &'s mut A
    c: C<'s>
}

fn construct_c<'s>(a: &'s mut A, d: &'s D) -> C<'s> {
    let mut b = B::new(a, d);
    modify(&mut b);
    b.extract_c()
}
```

to

```rust
struct B<'s, 'c> {
    a: &'s mut A
    c: C<'c>
}

fn construct_c<'s, 'c>(a: &'s mut A, d: &'c D) -> C<'c> {
    let mut b = B::new(a, d);
    modify(&mut b);
    b.extract_c()
}
```

Now each lifetime can vary independently, and in particular, the `'c` lifetime is allowed to be longer than `'s`.

That said, I have to warn you that you may be trying to use references where owned data would be better. A common beginner mistake is to try to build data storage structures out of references, and this is usually not a good idea because it either turns out impossible, or highly constrains how the structure can be used.

Comment: Shouldn't your second `struct B` above use lifetime `'a` for 'a'?

Comment: @kevin Thanks for the answer, introducing another lifetime fixed the issue. As for why C has a lifetime - when it is constructed, it takes another reference to another struct provided in construct_c which I omitted for brevity. I'm quite new to Rust so I thought that it wasn't that important to include it, but now I can see that it is quite confusing. I'll edit the question and clarify that.

Comment: @miloszwasacz Thanks for the clarification; I've updated my answer to match.